# In multer file extension which shouldnt be saved getting saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

TASK OF CODE : The code telling multer to save file with pdf extension

PROBLEM : I am getting back error in response but the file getting saved inside the folder

```
const express = require("express");
const app = new express();
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({
  dest: "images", // destination to save the image
  limits: 100000, // limiting the size of file to 1mb and 1 mb = 100000bytes
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.endsWith("pdf")) {
      cb(new Error("please upload PDF file extension")); // sending error
    }
    cb(undefined, true);
    // 3 type of call backs
    // cb(new Error('please upload PDF file extension'));// sending error
    // cb(undefined,true)// undefined means no error and true means accepting file
    // cb(undefined,false)// undefined means no error and true means rejecting file
  },
});
app.post("/upload", upload.single("upload"), (req, res) => {
  res.send();
});
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("server fired off");
});
```

The error message is correct as per what I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wyCR.jpg)
But the file is getting saved in images folder which should not be saved because I am sending jpg extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the code execution continues after `cb(new Error(..)`, thus `cb(undefined,true)` gets called as well, telling multer that everything is ok. Change it to:

```
if (!file.originalname.toLowerCase().endsWith("pdf")) {
  return cb(new Error("please upload PDF file extension")); // sending error
}
cb(undefined, true);
```

Note that I also used `.toLowerCase()` just to be sure that files with a`.PDF` extension get uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this new function called *checkFileType()*

```
function checkFileType(file, cb){
   const filetypes = /pdf/;
   const extname = filetypes.test(file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length-1]);
   const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
   if(mimetype && extname){
       return cb(null,true);
   }else{
       cb(error = 'message : please upload PDF file extension');
   }
}
```

And I implemented it like this

```
const upload = multer({
   dest: "images", // destination to save the image
   limits: 100000, // limiting the size of file to 1mb and 1 mb = 100000bytes
   fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
   },
});
```

Comment: A little advice since you are new here - you should add a bit of explanation to your answer, not just some code. Also in your example the `return` statement is not needed, since you use `if/else` and there is no code afterwards.